# What is the use of "using namespace std"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, using

What is the use of `using namespace std`?

I'd like to see explanation in Layman terms.

Comment: In layman terms, *don't do that*. [Here be dragons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/464709).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfgcEjCd9as

Answer (score 95):

- **using**: You are going to use it.
- **namespace**: To use what? A namespace.
- **std**: The `std` namespace (where features of the C++ Standard Library, such as `string` or `vector`, are declared).

After you write this instruction, if the compiler sees `string` it will know that you may be referring to `std::string`, and if it sees `vector`, it will know that you may be referring to `std::vector`. (Provided that you have included in your compilation unit the header files where they are defined, of course.)

If you *don't* write it, when the compiler sees `string` or `vector` it will not know what you are refering to. You will need to explicitly tell it `std::string` or `std::vector`, and if you don't, you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 33):

When you make a call to `using namespace <some_namespace>;` all symbols in that namespace will become visible without adding the namespace prefix. A symbol may be for instance a function, class or a variable.

E.g. if you add `using namespace std;` you can write just `cout` instead of `std::cout` when calling the operator `cout` defined in the namespace `std`.

This is somewhat dangerous because namespaces are meant to be used to avoid name collisions and by writing `using namespace` you spare some code, but loose this advantage. A better alternative is to use just specific symbols thus making them visible without the namespace prefix. Eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello world!";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bare in mind there are subtle differences between a *using-directive* and a *using-declaration* in regards to name lookup.

Comment: @Simple I wanted to keep it simple because Op requested explanation in layman terms.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that *using-directives* and *using-declarations* are also subject to scope. Using *using* isn't universally bad.

Comment: Suppose one wishes to load everything from `std`. How to do? `using std::` only?

Comment: if you want to load everything from the namespace you should be write `using namespace std` as I have written in my answer. However you should be aware of the consequences and you should only be using that if you really need it