# How does C++ know where to look for the namespace specified using "using namespace ..."?

Tags: c++, opencv, namespaces

For eg., when using OpenCV, we specify
    `using namespace cv;`
But where does C++ look down to know where it is defined?

Comment: After preprocessing, it's defined somewhere prior to this statement, in the same file.

Comment: The namespace will be found in the current translation unit.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but possibly it is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914106/what-is-the-use-of-using-namespace-std

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using namespace` will not make everything declared in that namespace visible. It will expose only what translation unit "sees".
Consider following code

One.h

```
#pragma once
namespace ns
{
  void function1();
}
```

Two.h

```
#pramga once
namespace ns
{
  void function2();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Two.h" // <-- included only Two.h
using namespace ns;

int main()
{
  function2(); // <-- is a ns::function2() located in Two.h
  function1(); // <-- error compiler does not know where to search for the function
  return 0;
}
```

What happened here is the compiler created translation unit with all preprocessor directives resolved. It will look something like this:

```
namespace ns
{
  void function2();
}
using namespace ns;

int main()
{
  function2(); // <-- OK. Declaration is visible
  function1(); // <-- Error. No declaration
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BillGates call of overloaded 'function()' is ambiguous. [You can check it yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeda1b74b4749bd2)

Comment: Ok! Btw the answer was just exactly for what I _intended_ to ask... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How does C++ know where to look for the namespace specified using `using namespace …`?

It doesn't.

When you use

```
using namespace cv;
```

the scope of search for names (of classes, functions, variables, enums, etc) is expanded. The names are searched in the `cv` namespace in addition to other scopes in which they are normally searched.