# 'list' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, list, namespaces

I am new to c++, and I am trying to get a basic program to initialize a list of short unsigned integers. I am compiling and running using scygwin and g++.

Below is the code in the .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

list<int> events;

return 0;
}
```

which I run by typing the following command into cygwin terminal:

```
$ g++ -o test.out test.cpp
```

However, I get the following compilation errors:

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: test.cpp:16:1: error:
>   ‘list’ was not declared in this scope  list events;
>    ^
>   test.cpp:16:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’ 
>   list events;
>        ^

I am confused about why list is not in the scope, since I am using namespace std? I found a similar question asked about this on a c++ forum, but my problem would be resolved with that. Anyone know what the problem is here?

-Paul

Comment: #include <list>

Comment: thank you. but why isn't that automatically included when I do `using namespace std`?

Comment: When you #include a file, it's like a literal copy paste. You get a lot of items that are hidden within namespace std. When you say `using namespace std;` you're not actually importing anything, but rather just saving yourself the trouble of having to qualify items within that namespace.

Comment: just to be clear, you're saying that <list> is hidden within namespace std until I explicitly include it? I guess I have been assuming that there is always an implicit `#include <std>` in every c++ file, which would give you access to anything in that namespace.

Comment: The namespace isn't a collection of code. It is simply a naming label that helps organize code. See my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using namespace std;` doesn't add any functionality to your code. It just means you don't have to type `std::` when referencing things in the `std` namespace, like `std::list`.

To actually include the code base for `std::list` into your program, you need to add:

```
#include <list>
```

When in doubt about this kind of thing, doing a google search for `cpp reference list` will turn up a page like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) where you can see: `Defined in header <list>` at the top.

Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914106/what-is-the-use-of-using-namespace-std) about `using namespace std;` that may prove useful and [why you shouldn't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice). I'll add a little bit to perhaps explain namespaces.

It is common in C++ programs to organize functions into classes and namespaces. Imagine you wrote your own `list` class to handle certain scenarios. In order to prevent naming conflicts you would put it in a different namespace than `std`.

```
namespace MyApp {
    class list;
    void sort(list&);
}
```

For the majority of a large code base you might still prefer to use `std::list` but you need `MyApp::list` for some things. Using namespaces you can cluster your code and prevent naming conflicts for similar functionality.

**Summary**

`using namespace std;` makes it so that if you reference a function or class not in the global namespace it looks for it in the `std` namespace.

`#include <list>` actually inserts prototypes (information about how to access the code) in your source file during the preprocessor stage.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. But I still don't understand why, if list is in the std library, I still have to explicitly include it?

Comment: all of your includes are in the standard library, the idea is you only include what you need

Comment: @Paul I've added a little more content to hopefully give you a better picture of what `using namespace` does and what `#include <list>` does

Comment: great, and thank you for the explanation. Actually, I think my main confusion was even simpler, and was answered finally by what @vu1p3n0x said. I didn't realize all packages I am usually including are in the std library, so I thought `#include` was more like an import.

Comment: If you're coming from a java/c# background I believe the correlation between `using` in the two languages is quite similar. `#include` is closer to java's `import`. With C# I'm unaware of anything like `import`/`#include`. The closest I can think of is including other libraries in the linking stage of a C# app.